# xAct : how to define f to be a function of two variables?

Tags: xact

f is a function of the coordinates x and y, how can I use the command `DefScalarFunction` to do this?

```
DefChart[ch,M,{0,1,2,3},{t[],x[],y[],z[]}]
DefScalarFunction[f]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify the number of arguments of a scalar function in xTensor. You just need to to specify that it is a scalar function, as you did, with DefScalarFunction[f]. Then you can use it with any number of arguments you want, say f[x[], y[]]. Of course, you should use it in your work with consistent arguments.